# R survey confidence interval plots

Tags: r, survey

Similarly to barplot and dotchart (from the survey package) barNest (plotrix package) was meant to produce plots for svyby objects on the fly,but also plotted confidence intervals. However barNest.svymean is no longer working on survey data. An alternative would be to plot confidence intervals on top of the survey plotting function dotchart

```
library(survey)
data(api)
dclus1<-svydesign(id=~dnum, weights=~pw, data=apiclus1, fpc=~fpc)
#just one variable        
a<-svyby(~api99, ~stype, dclus1, svymean)
#several variables
b<-svyby(~api99+api00, ~stype, dclus1, svymean)
dotchart(b)
```

although I'm not sure how you'd do that. If anyone works this out then it would be really good to automate it (by creating some code that applies to svyby objects of different sizes) and maybe even incoroporate it in dotchart.svystat {survey}. It would make graphic comparison among groups much easier! The standard errors can be extrated from b or using SE(b).

Comment: When reporting errors one is expected to provide sufficient details. The code runs fine on my machine. Using R 2.15.2, plotrix_3.4-5,  survey_3.29 which as far as I can tell are all the current versions. You haven't even described what "not working" means to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right so you're trying to use an object class (svyby) in a function (barNest) that doesn't know how to handle that class, because the survey package and the plotrix package don't play together too nicely.  luckily the dotchart method for svyby objects isn't too much code, so you might just want to modify it..

```
    # run your code above, then review the dotchart method for svyby objects:
    getS3method( 'dotchart' , 'svyby' )
```

..and from that you can learn it's really not much beyond calling the original dotchart function (that is, not using the svyby object, just a regular collection of statistics), after converting the data contained in your `b` object to a matrix.  now all you have left to do is add a confidence interval line.

the confidence interval widths are easily obtained (easier than using `SE(b)`) by running

```
    confint( b )
```

can you extract those statistics to build your own `barNest` or `plotCI` call?

if it's important to put confidence intervals on a dotchart, the major hurdle is hitting the y coordinates correctly.  dig around in the dotchart default method..

```
    getS3method( 'dotchart' , 'default' )
```

..and you can see how the y coordinates are calculated.  whittled down to just the essentials, i think you can use this:

```
    # calculate the distinct groups within the `svyby` object
    groups <- as.numeric( as.factor( attr( b , 'row.names' ) ) )

    # calculate the distinct statistics within the `svyby` object
    nstats <- attr( b , 'svyby' )$nstats

    # calculate the total number of confidence intervals you need to add
    n <- length( groups ) * nstats

    # calculate the offset sizes
    offset <- cumsum(c(0, diff(groups) != 0))

    # find the exact y coordinates for each dot in the dotchart
    # and leave two spaces between each group
    y <- 1L:n + sort( rep( 2 * offset , nstats ) )

    # find the confidence interval positions
    ci.pos <- 
        rep( groups , each = nstats ) + 
        c( 0 , length( groups ) )

    # extract the confidence intervals
    x <- confint( b )[ ci.pos , ]

    # add the y coordinates to a new line data object
    ld <- data.frame( x )

    # loop through each dot in the dotchart..
    for ( i in seq_len( nrow( ld ) ) ){

        # add the CI lines to the current plot
        lines( ld[ i , 1:2 ] , rep( y[i] , 2 ) )

    }
```

but that's obviously clunky since the confidence intervals are allowed to go way off the screen.  ignoring the `svyby` class and even the whole `survey` package for a second, find us implementation of `dotchart` that formats confidence intervals nicely, and we may be able to help you more.  i don't think the `survey` package is the root of your problem  :)

Comment: Anthony, you're a star. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just change line.data by ld.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a new dotchart plot (with min and max) to Anthony's last bit (from ld<-data.frame(x)) solves the problem he outlined.

```
ld <- data.frame( x )
dotchart(b,xlim=c(min(ld),max(ld)))#<-added
for ( i in seq_len( nrow( ld ) ) ){  
  lines( ld[ i , 1:2 ] , rep( y[i] , 2 ) )
}
```

However I agree with Anthony: the plot doesn't look great. Many thanks to Anthony for sharing his knowledge and programming skills. The confidence intervals also look asymmetrical (which might be right), particularly for M api00. Has anyone compared this with other software? Should confit specify a df (degrees of freedom)?

Comment: `?svyciprop` lists all of the confidence interval calculation options, including specifying the `df=` and shows an example that matches stata exactly..you can read more about Dr. Lumley implementing the [exact stata match here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2012-September/324464.html)